# Unirest post method doesn't work?

Tags: php, post, unirest

I have a very short code snippet taken directly from mashape:

I've included the paths correctly, as follows:

```
require_once 'unirest-php-master/src/Unirest.php';
```

And the code snippet to send a POST request:

```
$response = Unirest::post("",
      array(
        "X-Mashape-Key" => "",
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept" => "application/json"
      ),
      array(
        "selector" => "FACE, EYES, FULL",
        "url" => "http://api.animetrics.com/img/test/sc.jpg"
      )
    );
```

(I intentionally left the post("url") and the X-Mashape-Key blank since they're private keys.)

I'm not sure why this doesn't work - I tried echoing dummy text in the post method in the corresponding file by adding a method:

```
public static function echo($a) {
    echo $a;
}
```

in Request.php, but when I tried calling this method with `Unirest::echo("abc");` it didn't work either. Is there something wrong with this syntax or is there another problem I'm not seeing?

I'm 100% sure that my file path is right. I feel like I'm missing some obvious fact that I'm not seeing - would appreciate your help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The release of [Unirest 2.0](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php/releases/tag/2.0.0) had some breaking changes, mainly the method & class signature has changed. unfortunately the Mashape sample snippets are yet to be updated.

for example: instead of calling `Unirest::post` you should be calling `Unirest\Request::post`, please refer to the [unirest documentation](http://unirest.io/php.html) for more details.

We'll be updating the Mashape samples soon to reflect this change.

*I'm the author of unirest-php and I work at Mashape.*